# Is metadata generated from a server readable from crawlers and bots?

Tags: c#, seo, metadata, keyword, bots

I am currently facing the scenario where the server generates and returns metadata to pages.

My question is: Are those metadata readable from crawlers and bots? Can google read those metas (description and keywords)?

Does the same thing happen for metadata generated from Javascript?

- P.S. 1: Code is based on C# ([Umbraco](http://umbraco.com/))
- P.S. 2: If it's generally wrong to generate metadata this way, what alternative methods are available for dynamic metadata? (This is not another question, rather than asking for an advice or two).
- P.S. 3: Due to downvotes with no reason, I may have asked a broad question so:

The view page renders metas based on the [CurrentPage](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/views) model

```cs
@section headMetas {
    @Html.Raw(NavHelper.FetchMeta(CurrentPage))
}
```

then, the **FetchMeta** function will read a value from the model and will return it to the view as

```html
<meta name="description" content="blah blah">
```

Since this is an action made by the server, will it be rendered when crawlers visit the site, thus reading metas from the DOM?

- P.S. 4: Not all pages are available without validation. Not accessible pages do not have metas and will not have any. This question concerns only the pages available to everyone.

Comment: If the site doesn't require a login assume the meta data is being read by Google, even meta data produced by JavaScript

Comment: Site doesn't require a login but there is some form of validation; user must accept some terms before entering the main page. Main page though (and others that require user validation) don't have metadata and won't have any

Comment: Sorry I don't write Googles bot but if filling out a form is required (at this point in time) I doubt a search engine would be bothered. This question is very subjective, in short have you ever seen a record in a dB as a result of search engine company ? It scans everything else though. Unfortunately getting meta data indexed isn't the holy grail for SEO.

Comment: Normally I would ask the reason behind the downvote, but downvoting a question you don't understand for an answer you don't have isn't the best practice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is about SEO

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After using various SEO tools to check whether metas are rendered, I came to conclusion that bots/crawlers do trigger server side code.

So, to answer my question, metadata generated from server ARE readable from bots/crawlers.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question but I wouldn't get too hung up on that. This answer would be good if there was some data to back up your conclusion.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "some data". I said that I used SEO tools that claim to scan a given page for errors and warnings against some generic SEO guidelines. All of them had a successful mark, for the pages I care, that they do have description and keywords, which they were rendered in their result boxes. What more evidence do I need?